# Mongoose function logs correct data but using async function to get it returns undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to query some data from a database and return it to a function. The issue I am having is that when I log the results from the query it is working but when I try to query what the function is returning I am getting undefined. It could be that my async function with mongoose isn't exactly set up correctly. Or maybe I just have the wrong idea of what is happening as I am new to the idea of asynchronous programming.

```
async function returnBlogThumbnails(filter = "recent", callback){
    console.log("returning blogs")
    //For now simply filter by most recent
        if(filter === "recent"){
            Blog.find({}).sort('-date').exec((err,docs) => {
                return docs;
            });
        }
}
```

and the function that calls this function

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    console.log("go home");
    //Call out to query the database then use async function to return 
    database.returnBlogThumbnails().then((blogs) => {
        console.log(blogs);
        //res.render('home', blogs);
    });
});
```

As I have said the console.log spits out what I am looking for. However, the function calling the function with the query always shows undefined. Thanks

Comment: Your `returnBlogThumbnails` function isn't returning anything. You're also mixing callbacks & promises which leads to confusing code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you defined your function with callback and trying to call it as a promise. Your function with promise should be:

```
async function returnBlogThumbnails(filter = "recent") {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {     // creates a promise
        console.log("returning blogs")
        //For now simply filter by most recent
        if (filter === "recent") {
            Blog.find({}).sort('-date').exec((err, docs) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(docs)
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and then in your route you can call it as:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("go home");
    //Call out to query the database then use async function to return 
    database.returnBlogThumbnails()
        .then((blogs) => {
            console.log(blogs);
            // do something with blogs
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            // handle error
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly my issue. I am new to javascript so this all hasn't really stuck!

Comment: my pleasure, happy coding :)